# Rendering multiple Models each containing multiple objects in Ember Js

Tags: ember.js

I'm quite new to EmberJS. I am trying to render a simple hasMany modelisation.

My app is supposed to handle multiple tasks for multiple persons.

First, I have models:

```
App.Task = Em.Object.extend({
    name: null
});
App.Person = Em.Object.extend({
    firstname: null,
    lastname: null,
    avatar: null,
    tasks:null,
});
```

A person can have multiple tasks. So my personsController works like this:

```
App.personsController = Em.ArrayController.create({
    content: [],
    tasks:[],
    addPerson: function(){
        var aPerson = App.Person.create({
            firstname: this.firstname,
            lastname : this.lastname,
            avatar : this.avatar,
        });
        this.pushObject( aPerson );  
    }
```

My tasksController, wich will handle tasks jobs:

```
App.tasksController = Em.ArrayController.create({
    content:[],
    contentBinding: "App.personsController.tasks",
    name:'',
    removeTask: function(e){
        this.removeObject( e.context );
    },
    addTask: function(e){
        this.pushObject( App.Task.create({"name":this.name}) );
    }
});
```

`contentBiding` seems to be one of the keys here. I want it to auto-bind to the tasks of the person I'm working on.

On the views side, just working on my Handlebars templates:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  {{view Em.TextField valueBinding="App.personsController.firstname" placeholder="firstname" }}
  {{view Em.TextField valueBinding="App.personsController.lastname" placeholder="lastname" }}
  <button {{action "addPerson" target="App.personsController"}} class="btn btn-primary"  >Ajouter un developpeur</button>
    {{#each App.personsController}}
      <div>
        <h3>{{firstname}}{{lastname}}</h3>
      {{view Em.TextField valueBinding="App.tasksController.name"}} 
        <button {{action "addTask" target="App.tasksController"}}  >Add a task</button>
        {{#each App.tasksController}}
          {{view Em.TextField valueBinding="name" }}
          <button {{action "removeTask" target="App.tasksController"}}  >x</button>
        {{/each}}
      </div>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

So, when I'm adding a new person, everything works fine. But if I add a task, the task is added on each of the person's tasks in the view.

I'm afraid I'm making a conceptual mistake, and I can't find a good documentation about this kind of visualisation. I've seen examples of hasMany relations with ember.data, but I'd like first to understand properly what is going on here.

Answer (score 0):

Your `addTask` function adds a new task to the array maintained within `App.tasksController`, but there is nothing binding these tasks to any instance of `App.Person.tasks`.

I suggest creating new `View` class with a binding to your `tasksController` and to a *single* `App.Person` instance. The personBinding of this view would be set inside of your outer `{{#each}}` loop. Have this view be responsible for rendering `App.Person.tasks` for a single person.

Change `addTask` in your controller to accept a reference to an `App.Person` as an argument, then add the task explicitly to that person's `tasks` array in the body of the function.